# Motherboard with separate circuitry for PCIe, CPU, RAM etc

Tags: cpu, ram, pcie, motherboard

I asked this question on another forum (http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1812014/motherboard-separate-circuitry-pcie-cpu-ram.html) but nobody replied yet so posting it here

I am looking for an 1-socket Intel Motherboard with separate circuitry for PCIe, CPU, RAM etc. so that we can measure power consumption for each of those components separately. Do you know any such motherboard from Intel (or even ASUS/GigaBit) that supports some decent (4-core) SandyBridge/Ivy-Bridge/Haswell Xeon processor?

Also, how can I check if a specific motherboard has separate circuitry or not?

Waiting for your reply.

Comment: x86-class machines haven't had separate circuitry for each subsystem for decades.

Comment: You can get PCI risers or extension kits, so you can measure the consumption of an individual card; however, separating the CPU and RAM power will probably be very hard.

Comment: why down-voted. True this question is not much clear, but it's something could be answered.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're in luck today. All motherboards have completely separate power supplies for basically all the building blocks - at least up until Haswell. And even in Haswell-PCs, the parts that have been integrated into the processor (voltage regulator controllers) are not the current-carrying parts, and you will still be able to directly measure the power going into the different voltage planes. I've been doing exactly what you want to do for about 3 years now and have never really found big problems isolating single-chip power consumption.

Just lift all the inductors and linear power supplies you can find on the board and put a little shunt resistor in series with them.

Here's a link to my blog where you should get a reasonable idea of how to go about this business: [mux' blog](http://ssj3gohan.tweakblogs.net/blog/8217/fluffy2-59-watt-high-end-desktop-computer.html)